# C# List that that accepts 2 or more enum types

Tags: c#, types

I have these multiple enums used as Ids and want to use them in a single list.

```
public enum eUnit
{
    Villager,
    Warrior,
    Wizard,
}
public enum eVehicle
{
    Car,
    Train,
    Helicopter,
}
public enum eItem
{
    Apple,
    Steak,
    Pizza,
}
```

Is something like the code below possible?

```
List<?enum?> myList = new List<?enum?>();
myList.Add(eUnit.Warrior);
myList.Add(eItem.Pizza);

if(myList[0].GetType() == typeof(eUnit))
    DoStuff();
...
...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Strongly typed collections are made to stop you from adding element of different types. Even if you treat all enums as their underlying integers, how would you tell what enum they originated from?

Comment: Consider dropping enum and using class polymorphism and interfaces instead.

Comment: Enums are actually integers. So you might need a tuple instead with type and value.

`List<(Type type, int val)> list = new List<(Type, int)>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way is to use a discriminated union via [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) library.

```cs
var myList = new List<OneOf<eUnit, eVehicle, eItem>>()
{
    eUnit.Warrior, eVehicle.Car
};
myList[0].Switch(
    unit => Console.WriteLine("Unit"),
    vehicle => Console.WriteLine("Vehicle"),
    item => Console.WriteLine("Item")
);
```

I made a [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZYEMP)

---

Comment: It will be fun to unbox that...

Comment: @djv: A OneOf instance stores not only the value itself but also *which* of the types it contains (i.e., an index from 0 to 2 in the case of three possible types). So the enum type information is not lost during boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Heinzi cool, but my comment was on a previous edit with `List<object> myList = new List<object>()`

Comment: @djv: Ah, ok, makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the type dynamic. Perhaps it would be overkill but it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `List<T>`. Here is a simple example :

```
public class EnumList
{
    private readonly List<Entry> _entriesList = new List<Entry>();
    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            var item = _entriesList[index];
            return Enum.Parse(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            _entriesList[index] = new Entry(value.GetType(), value.ToString());
        }
    }

    private class Entry
    {
        public Type Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Entry(Type key, string value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add<TEnum>(TEnum item) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        _entriesList.Add(new Entry(typeof(TEnum), item.ToString()));
    }

    public List<TEnum> Get<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        return _entriesList.Where(x => x.Key == typeof(TEnum)).Select(x => Enum.TryParse(x.Value, out TEnum result) ? result : default).ToList();
    }

    public bool Exists<TEnum>(TEnum item) where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        return _entriesList.Any(x => x.Key == typeof(TEnum) && x.Value == item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var list = new EnumList();

list.Add(eUnit.Warrior);
list.Add(eItem.Pizza);
list.Add(eVehicle.Car);
list.Add(eVehicle.Helicopter);
list.Add(eUnit.Villager);
list.Add(eItem.Apple);

if((eUnit)list[0] ==  eUnit.Warrior || list.Exists(eUnit.Villager))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is just a sample to help you implement your own, remember, you should always try to narrow the acceptable params by specifying the intended `enum`s, you could go full generic though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Andriy, using a discriminated union such as the `OneOf`, or `Either` can be useful in this case.

If you are just using the enums as an ID, you could also create various classes and utilize the type system for pattern matching. This is just a different pattern you could look into if you like pattern matching against specific items.

```cs
internal abstract class EnumType
{
    protected EnumType(int value, string name)
    {
        if(value < 0) { throw new InvalidOperationException("Value cannot be less than 0."); }
        this._value = value;
        this._name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    public static implicit operator int(EnumType x)
        => x?._value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));

    public static implicit operator string(EnumType x)
        => x?._name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));

    private readonly int _value;
    private readonly string _name;
}

internal sealed class eUnit : EnumType
{
    private eUnit(int value, string name): base(value, name) { }

    // operator overloads like |, &, ^, etc...

    internal static readonly eUnit Villager = new eUnit(0, "Villager");
    internal static readonly eUnit Warrior = new eUnit(1, "Warrior");
    internal static readonly eUnit Wizard = new eUnit(2, "Wizard");
}

internal sealed class eItem : EnumType
{
    private eItem(int value, string name): base(0, "Apple") { }

    // operator overloads like |, &, ^, etc...

    internal static readonly eItem Apple = new eItem(0, "Apple");
    internal static readonly eItem Steak = new eItem(1, "Steak");
    internal static readonly eItem Pizza = new eItem(2, "Pizza");
}
```

This would allow you to then write:

```cs
var myList = new List<EnumType>();
myList.Add(eUnit.Warrior);
myList.Add(eItem.Pizza);

if (myList[0] is eUnit eUnit)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

If you cared about further granularity, you could turn those static fields into classes as well, along the lines of:

```cs
internal abstract class eUnit : EnumType
{
    private eUnit(int value, string name): base(value, name) { }

    // operator overloads like |, &, ^, etc...

    internal sealed class Villager : eUnit
    {
        private Villager(): base(0, "Villager") { }
        internal static readonly Villager _ = new Villager();
    }

    internal sealed class Warrior : eUnit
    {
        private Warrior(): base(1, "Warrior") { }
        internal static readonly Warrior _ = new Warrior();
    }

    internal sealed class Wizard : eUnit
    {
        private Wizard(): base(2, "Wizard") { }
        internal static readonly Wizard _ = new Wizard();
    }
}

internal abstract class eItem : EnumType
{
    private eItem(int value, string name): base(0, "Apple") { }

    // operator overloads like |, &, ^, etc...

    //...

    internal sealed class Pizza : eItem
    {
        private Pizza(): base(2, "Pizza") { }
        internal static readonly Pizza _ = new Pizza();
    }
}
```

Then your sample would be rewritten as:

```cs
var myList = new List<EnumType>();
myList.Add(eUnit.Warrior._);
myList.Add(eItem.Pizza._);

var result = myList[0] switch
{
    eUnit eUnit => eUnit switch
    {
        eUnit.Villager villager => DoVillagerStuff(villager),
        eUnit.Warrior warrior => DoWarriorStuff(warrior),
        eUnit.Wizard wizard => DoWizardStuff(wizard),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknonwn eItem");
    },
    eItem eItem = eItem switch
    {
        eItem.Pizza pizza => DoPizzaStuff(pizza),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported eItem")
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look at the `ArrayList` class:

```
public enum eUnit
{
    Villager,
    Warrior,
    Wizard,
}

public enum eVehicle
{
    Car,
    Train,
    Helicopter,
}

public enum eItem
{
    Apple,
    Steak,
    Pizza,
}

void Main()
{
    var myList = new ArrayList();
    
    myList.Add(eUnit.Warrior);
    myList.Add(eItem.Pizza);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        var element = myList[i];
        if (element is eUnit unit)
            Console.WriteLine($"Element at index {i} is eUnit {unit}");
        else if (element is eVehicle vehicle)
            Console.WriteLine($"Element at index {i} is eVehicle {vehicle}");
        else if (element is eItem item)
            Console.WriteLine($"Element at index {i} is eItem {item}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Element at index {i} is another type");
    }
}
```